# How do I consume this second promise?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, asynchronous-javascript

Here's the code

```
console.log("Before");
const p = getUser(1);
p.then(user => {
  console.log(user);
  getRepositories(user.github);
}).then(repos => {
  console.log(repos);
});

console.log("after");

function getUser(id) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Calling a database " + id);
      resolve({ id: id, github: "Zain" });
    }, 2000);
  });
}

function getRepositories(username) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`Calling Api for ${username}`);
      resolve(["repo1", "repo2", "repo3"]);
    }, 2000);
  });
}
```

I'm having trouble with consuming the promise returned by `getRepositories()` function. Above is my implementation but it doesn't work and returns `undefined` (instead of the array `[repo1, repo2, repo3]`).

Here's the output:
[image]

I want the array to return after logging "Calling Api for Zain" but the `undefined` is shown before it, but I don't know why, so I need help regarding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a return statement in your first `.then`:

```
p.then(user => {
  console.log(user);
  return getRepositories(user.github);
}).then(repos => {
  console.log(repos);
});
```

Comment: yes this solved the problem.. But out of curiosity, why do we need the return statement? Because I've watched some tutorials on yt but they didn't use the return statement. They chained the functions

Comment: When you call `.then` you create a new promise. That promise will resolve to whatever the function returns. I'm guessing the tutorials didn't care what the promise resolved to, so they just left it the return off, and so they implicitly returned undefined.

Comment: oh ok.. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

There’s a special syntax to work with promises in a more comfortable fashion, called `“async/await”`. It’s surprisingly easy to understand and use.

```
async function init() {
  console.log("Before");
  const user = await getUser(1);
  console.log(user);
  const repos = await getRepositories(user.github);
  console.log(repos);
  console.log("after");
}
init();

async function getUser(id) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Calling a database " + id);
      resolve({ id: id, github: "Zain" });
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function getRepositories(username) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`Calling Api for ${username}`);
      resolve(["repo1", "repo2", "repo3"]);
    }, 2000);
  });
}
```

For more information: https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: Wow, this is easier. Thanks for sharing this

Comment: @ohnope Thanks for replying.